# Combining multiple k8s kustomizations into one

Tags: kubernetes, kustomize

In Kubernetes I have a base kustomize package, and two patches to it, each patch adjusting a different aspect of the base - one for large deployment, and another to use a legacy image rather than the current one.  Is there a way I can create a "combined" patch -- the one that has both changes, without copying large & legacy patch content?

```
- base/
- large-deployment-patch/
- legacy-image-patch/
```

When I tried to simply use both patches as bases in the combined patch, I get an error like this:

`Error: ../legacy: id '"~G_v1_ConfigMap|~X|~P|pg-database|~S"' already used`

Comment: It looks like `large-deployment-patch` and `legacy-image-patch` are `overlay`s rather than `patch`es in kustomize terminology. Can you confirm?

Comment: Assuming they are overlays, what is the base for each overlay?

Comment: @Jamie it's a bit more complex -- one is an image label change (stored in kustomize.yaml itself), another is a patch, but they both change aspects of the same base object (stored in the base dir).  In my case I actually have two more aspects that needs changing, so I end up with a dir for each combination of changes - which is very hard to manage.

Answer (score 3):

As @Jamie mentioned in his comment, if any of the two "Patches" contains a `kustomization.yaml` file that include your `base/` directory as a resource, it will be an overlay. Each overlay generates a copy of all the resources in your base and modify them.

If your base creates a `ConfigMap` called `pg-database` and none of your overlays modifies the name of this resource, you will end-up with two `ConfigMap`s called `pg-database`.

So to sum-up: each overlay creates a copy of the resources and you can't have two resources of the same `kind` with the same `name` in the same `namespace`.

It's common practice to add a `namePrefix` or `nameSuffix` transformer in your overlays to avoid collisions and give more meaningful names to your resources.